# php socket write xml and keep alive

Tags: php, xml, sockets

I'm creating a new itegration with XIQS in php,
and they require to open a connection with a socket, then pass a login request with specific xml.

I'm able to create a socket but I cant pass the xml properly as I get 400 error all the time.

the docs: http://vpn.iqsim.com:8080/iqSimWiki/index.php?title=XIQS_Client_/_Server_Communications

my code:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding=“UTF-8"?>'."\n".'
    <command name="loginXIQS">'."\n".'
        <param type="string">USERNAME</param>'."\n".'
        <param type="string">PASSWORD</param>'."\n".'
    </command>'."\n";

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

$address = '217.108.104.101';
$service_port = 8000;

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} 
else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} 
else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Content-Type: text/xmlrn";
//$in.= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in.= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
$in.= "rn";
$in.= $xml;

$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
```

any ideas how to write xml to socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding=“UTF-8"?>'."\n".'
```

to

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".'
```

replace

```
$in .= "Content-Type: text/xmlrn";
```

to

```
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n";
```

Full working example

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".'
    <command name="loginXIQS">'."\n".'
        <param type="string">USERNAME</param>'."\n".'
        <param type="string">PASSWORD</param>'."\n".'
    </command>'."\n";

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

$address = '217.108.104.101';
$service_port = 8000;

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}
else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n";
//$in.= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Host: 217.108.104.101\r\n";
$in.= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
$in.= "rn";
$in.= $xml;

$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
```

Comment: I dont know what was change it the first line, but this is magic!

Comment: now you know maybe how do I get the response after each request I do? as I first login -> get login response, then I perform action -> I need action response and finally logout. Currently it lags on the while loop.

Comment: and how I get the content? as I supposably need to get a xml response...?

Comment: you receive an answer on asked question, other questions post as questions with properly description.

Comment: `“` is a typographic quote character and different from `"`. That broke the XML.

Comment: @cetver any ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513081/get-socket-response-body-after-posting-to-it